# how to get list of admin column name in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a custom WordPress plugin so I need to retrieve the list of all column in to my plugin file can anyone help me to how I get the list of below column.

in my case how I get list like.
I need a list like

author, title, Tags, categories, Date, Short code

[image]

Comment: You can look at the `manage_post_type_posts_columns` filter.

Comment: its applied filter while load particular post page but I need column list to display on fronted side for my custom work so have any idea how to get list ?